# error undefined reference while building a C++ project

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I have no clue what is this problem:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
```

I am building a C++ project with Cmake. Is there anyhow that I can check the details of the error?

Comment: What is the compilation command? It looks to me like you are either missing or not linking to the i686 libc.

Comment: Aren't there other error message before this one? Like for missing libc ?

Comment: set VERBOSE=1: `$ VERBOSE=1 make` and show us the invocation of the compiler/linker

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/undefined-reference-to-%60__libc_csu_fini-849247/

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicated question. I have tried those hints but still there is no clue about the problem

Comment: @Linuxios how can I check if I missed or did not link to the i686?

Comment: @chill it is strange that there is no error before this one

Comment: @piokuc yes, I have added VERBOSE=1 but there is not much helpful debug data

Comment: @olidev: Try adding `-lc` to your compile command.

Comment: @Linuxios thanks. what does -lc mean? I will try it tomorrow morning

Comment: @olidev: it means to link library (-l) C (c).

Comment: @Linuxios adding -lc does not add any value. Thanks

Comment: @olidev: Hm. That's odd.